# Scala list creation using class

Tags: scala, list, intellij-idea

I have a class called `Pharmacy` that has three fields. If I create a list within the class, it works just fine. However, if I try to create a list outside the class, I get some error about "The Application doesn't take any parameters" (an IntelliJ error).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
// This part gets an error
def getDrugInfo(str: String):Box[List[Pharmacy]] = {
    val pharmacies = List (
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
}

// This part works fine
object Pharmacy {

case class Pharmacy(name: String, address: String, acceptsCard: String)

val pharmacies = List(
  Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"),
      Pharmacy("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
}
```

Comment: Could you please post all the body of the `getDrugInfo` method ?

Comment: The whole method is there. Just had the curly brace outside the code box.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the Pharmacy case class inside of the Pharmacy Object.  Move it to a top-level declaration.

As it is, `Pharmacy` refers to the object you've declared, to get the inner case class you would need `Pharmacy.Pharmacy(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You used a `val ... = ...` inside the getDruginfo. `=` is a side-effecting call that returns Unit. So what you returning Unit, which isn't of the required return type.